# What is the advantage of assigning variable that is part of condition in while condition?

Tags: java

```
String var;
while((var = "abc") == "abc"){ 
    System.out.println("In loop"); 
}
```

What is the advantage of assigning a variable while doing a check for the condition in the while loop.

Comment: Aside: you can also assign a variable during its own declaration: `String var = (var = "abc").trim();`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In that example, there is none, but I assume you're talking about something like:

```
while ((var = obj.someMethod()) != null) {
    // ...use var...
}
```

...where `null` is any of several marker values depending on what `obj` and `someMethod` are. For instance, using `BufferedReader`'s [`readLine`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()), you might loop through lines like this:

```
while ((line = reader.nextLine()) != null) {
    // ...use the line...
}
```

This is a fairly common idiom when dealing with objects that have a method that keeps returning something useful until/unless it reaches the "end" of what it's working through, at which point it returns a marker value saying it's done (`null` is a common choice). The idiom is useful because it advances to the "next" thing, remembers the "next" thing, and checks for whether it's done.

But in your example, there'd be no point whatsoever. Also, it [compares strings incorrectly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java). :-)

Comment: Your explanation is fairly enhance my ask. However, out of curiosity, wouldn't it be simple to code like this. what would be wrong in this approach  while ((reader.nextLine()) != null) { // ...use the line... }

Comment: @Dasarathan - How would you `...use the line...` if you don't have it? `BufferedReader` doesn't have a `getLastLine` or similar method. Keeping track if the line it just gave you is *your* task. :-)

Comment: @t-j-crowder Ok got it. Helpful.